# How to provision rds instance inside vpc via puppet

Tags: puppet, aws-sdk, puppetlabs-aws

I'm trying to provision rds instance inside existing VPC using puppetlabs/aws module. I'm able to provision rds instance in non-VPC mode using following declaration of resource:

```
rds_instance { $instance_name:
        ensure              => present,
        allocated_storage   => $rds::params::allocated_storage,
        db_instance_class   => $rds::params::db_instance_class,
        db_name             => $db_name,
        engine              => $db_data['engine'],
        license_model       => $db_data['license_model'],
        db_security_groups  => $db_security_groups,
        master_username     => $master_username,
        master_user_password=> $master_user_password,
        region              => $region,
        skip_final_snapshot => $rds::params::skip_final_snapshot,
        storage_type        => $rds::params::storage_type,
    }
```

However, when I try to add additional attribute called: **db_subnet**, following error happens when trying to puppet apply:

> Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: unexpected value at params[:subnet_group_name]

I'm aware this error retrieves aws-sdk rather than puppet module itself.

If I'm correct, I need to pass subnet group name for db_subnet attribute and I've done but it results with issue from above. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the value you're passing as the `db_subnet`?